# Не работает Badge на иконке

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Доброго времени суток! У меня такая проблема: есть stepper, который выполняет такой код:

```
- (IBAction)changeValue:(id)sender
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = [self.stepper value];
}
```

Но ничего не работает. В консоли появляется такое:
Attempting to badge the application icon but haven't received permission from the user to badge the application

Как это исправить? Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // registering for remote notifications
    [self registerForRemoteNotification];
    return YES;
}


- (void)registerForRemoteNotification {
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")) {
        UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
        UIUserNotificationSettings *notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
    } else {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }
}

#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
#endif
```

[Гугл в помощь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25973364/attempting-to-badge-the-application-icon-but-havent-received-permission-from-th)